# How do I connect a 2008 server to a 2003 server active directory?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, permissions, active-directory

Our DC is running Windows Server 2003.

I've just set up Windows Server 2008 and have terminal server running on it.  When setting the terminal server permissions, it was able to allow a group name that was read from the domain.  In the DC the new terminal server shows up as a computer in the domain.

I can also log in as a user within the domain even though that user doesn't exist locally on the new server.

However, when I go to set sharing permissions on the new machine it doesn't show my domain as a location.  Instead it is only looking at location "machinename" and not allowing domain to be seen or added.  Is there something I'm missing?

Ok, lots of errors in the event log.

We have this:

> The winlogon notification subscriber
>    is taking long time to
>   handle the notification event (Logon).

Followed by this:

> The winlogon notification subscriber
>    took 121 second(s) to
>   handle the notification event (Logon).

Followed by:

> The processing of Group Policy failed
>   because of lack of network
>   connectivity to a domain controller.
>   This may be a transient condition. A
>   success message would be generated
>   once the machine gets connected to the
>   domain controller and Group Policy has
>   succesfully processed. If you do not
>   see a success message for several
>   hours, then contact your
>   administrator.

I think this might be the same problem I'm having
[Primary Domain Controller slow?](https://serverfault.com/questions/24420/primary-domain-controller-slow)

Solved.  The issue was that I had changed from DHCP to static and put the wrong DNS server IP in. i.e. firewall instead of DC/DNS server.

Comment: I'm also getting occasional login problems... the specified domain cannot be contacted etc... something funny going on because the DC is always there and it's only server 2008 thats having the issue.  It's on the same network.  Any logs I can look at?

Comment: Control Panel -> Admin Tools -> Event Viewer

The System events should give you a clue as to what is going on. They aren't always crystal clear, but post what you're seeing, or search on MS TechNet.

Comment: Please pop the solution in an answer and mark it as an the correct answer so this doesn't come up on the main page again. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with DNS.  I had changed the 2008 server from DHCP to static IP and put the wrong DNS server IP address in.

The DNS server needs to be our domain controller which is also running the DNS server for the Domain in our case.  Once I changed that, the terminal server was able to locate the domain controller correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're logged in to the terminal server as a domain account that has administrator rights on the terminal server.  Otherwise, the permissions dialogs will default to the local security database.

Comment: Yes I am logged on as an administrator who has full control to the domain and the terminal server.

Comment: Having said that, I rebooted the server and now I am seeing hosting.local.  But it's not able to search it.

Comment: No it's gone again, no longer showing hosting.local, just machinename as a location. Very flaky!